# XStream - Parsing nested elements (Skipping parent)

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing, xstream

I have the following XML that I'm trying to parse w/ XStream . The thing is, everything works fine up to the point where I reach `<Keywords>...</Keywords>` element.

I'd like to get all of the `<KEYWORD>` elements, without having to make a class to handle the `<KEYWORDS>`

Sample.XML

```
<CATALOG>
  <PRODUCTS>
    <PRODUCT>
      <PRODUCTOID>123</PRODUTOID>
      <PRODUCTNAME>TEST NAME</NOMEPRODUTO>
      <DESCRIPTION>TEST DESCRIPTION</DESCRIPTION>
      <KEYWORDS>
        <KEYWORD>keyword_1</KEYWORD>
        <KEYWORD>keyword_2</KEYWORD>
        <KEYWORD>keyword_3</KEYWORD>
        <KEYWORD>keyword_n</KEYWORD>
      <KEYWORDS>
    </PRODUCT>
  </PRODUCTS>
</CATALOG>
```

Catalog.java

```
@XStreamAlias("CATALOG")
public class Catalog {

    @XStreamAlias("PRODUCTS")
    private List<Product> products;

   // Getters and Setters

}
```

Products.java

```
@XStreamAlias("PRODUCT")
public class Product {

    @XStreamAlias("PRODUCTID")
    private String id;

    @XStreamAlias("PRODUCTNAME")
    private String name;

    @XStreamAlias("DESCRIPTION")
    private String description;


   // @XStreamImplicit(itemFieldName = "KEYWORD")
   // the above line works, *IF* I delete the parent node `<KEYWORDS>`,
   // but that's not the case, I have to deal with it  

   // @StreamAlias("KEYWORDS/KEYWORD")
   // this doesn't work

   @StreamAlias("KEYWORDS")
   // and this returns the error I'm posting below after this class
   private List<String> keywords;

   // Getters and Setters

}
```

XStreamTest.java

```
public class XStreamTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

    String filepath = "Sample.xml";

    try {
        FileReader reader = new FileReader(filepath);
        XStream xstream = new XStream();

        xstream.processAnnotations(Catalog.class);
        xstream.processAnnotations(Product.class);

        Catalog catalog = (Catalog) xstream.fromXML(reader);
        System.out.println(catalog.getProducts().get(0).getKeywords().get(0));
    }

    catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

With the current setup, this is what I'm getting (I'm aware why I'm getting this... I'm not mapping the element `<KEYWORD>` anywhere.

But I really *did NOT* want to make another class, say "Keyword.java" just to deal with that  `<KEYWORDS>` (like I did to manage the elements within the `<PRODUCT>` element.

Is there anyway I can solve this (without having to make another class) ?

```
Exception in thread "main" com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.ConversionException: KEYWORD: KEYWORD
---- Debugging information ----
message             : KEYWORD
cause-exception     : com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.CannotResolveClassException
cause-message       : KEYWORD
class               : java.util.ArrayList
required-type       : java.util.ArrayList
converter-type      : com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.collections.CollectionConverter
path                : /CATALOG/PRODUCTS/PRODUCT/KEYWORDS/KEYWORD
line number         : 9
class[1]            : obscured_package.model.Product
converter-type[1]   : com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.ReflectionConverter
class[2]            : obscured_package.model.Catalog
version             : 1.4.8
-------------------------------
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convert(TreeUnmarshaller.java:79)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractReferenceUnmarshaller.convert(AbstractReferenceUnmarshaller.java:65)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convertAnother(TreeUnmarshaller.java:66)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter.unmarshallField(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:480)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter.doUnmarshal(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:412)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter.unmarshal(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:263)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convert(TreeUnmarshaller.java:72)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractReferenceUnmarshaller.convert(AbstractReferenceUnmarshaller.java:65)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convertAnother(TreeUnmarshaller.java:66)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convertAnother(TreeUnmarshaller.java:50)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.collections.AbstractCollectionConverter.readItem(AbstractCollectionConverter.java:71)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.collections.CollectionConverter.addCurrentElementToCollection(CollectionConverter.java:98)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.collections.CollectionConverter.populateCollection(CollectionConverter.java:91)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.collections.CollectionConverter.populateCollection(CollectionConverter.java:85)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.collections.CollectionConverter.unmarshal(CollectionConverter.java:80)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convert(TreeUnmarshaller.java:72)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractReferenceUnmarshaller.convert(AbstractReferenceUnmarshaller.java:65)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convertAnother(TreeUnmarshaller.java:66)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter.unmarshallField(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:480)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter.doUnmarshal(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:412)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter.unmarshal(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:263)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convert(TreeUnmarshaller.java:72)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractReferenceUnmarshaller.convert(AbstractReferenceUnmarshaller.java:65)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convertAnother(TreeUnmarshaller.java:66)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convertAnother(TreeUnmarshaller.java:50)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.start(TreeUnmarshaller.java:134)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractTreeMarshallingStrategy.unmarshal(AbstractTreeMarshallingStrategy.java:32)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.unmarshal(XStream.java:1206)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.unmarshal(XStream.java:1190)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.fromXML(XStream.java:1061)
    at br.com.multiplusfidelidade.ecommerce.netshoes.batch.App.main(App.java:21)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:140)
Caused by: com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.CannotResolveClassException: PALAVRA
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.DefaultMapper.realClass(DefaultMapper.java:79)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:30)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.DynamicProxyMapper.realClass(DynamicProxyMapper.java:55)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:30)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.PackageAliasingMapper.realClass(PackageAliasingMapper.java:88)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:30)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.ClassAliasingMapper.realClass(ClassAliasingMapper.java:79)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:30)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:30)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:30)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:30)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:30)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:30)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.ArrayMapper.realClass(ArrayMapper.java:74)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:30)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:30)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:30)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:30)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:30)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:30)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:30)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.SecurityMapper.realClass(SecurityMapper.java:71)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:30)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:30)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.CachingMapper.realClass(CachingMapper.java:47)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.util.HierarchicalStreams.readClassType(HierarchicalStreams.java:29)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.collections.AbstractCollectionConverter.readItem(AbstractCollectionConverter.java:70)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.collections.CollectionConverter.addCurrentElementToCollection(CollectionConverter.java:98)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.collections.CollectionConverter.populateCollection(CollectionConverter.java:91)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.collections.CollectionConverter.populateCollection(CollectionConverter.java:85)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.collections.CollectionConverter.unmarshal(CollectionConverter.java:80)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convert(TreeUnmarshaller.java:72)
    ... 35 more

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I guess your XML would be parsed correctly if you had "string" where you have "KEYWORD" now. So I guess your question was already answered here: [aliasing-contents-of-a-set-using-xstream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8066917/aliasing-contents-of-a-set-using-xstream)

You could try [XStreamAliasType](http://x-stream.github.io/javadoc/com/thoughtworks/xstream/annotations/XStreamAliasType.html) to do it with an annotation.

Comment: the thing is: it's a real life application where the Input XML is just like the sample I wrote, I don't have the option to set it as "String" where "Keyword " is. And I really would like to avoid using String.replace to change that for String....

Comment: That's why I suggest that you explain xstream to understand the type "String" when it reads "KEYWORD". That's what the linked answer does with method calls and the linked annotation (I hope) does in your data class.

Comment: I checked that link you refered me to, but it does exactly the opposite I'm trying to do, it's an Object being serialized into an XML, what I need an XML serialized into an Object. I did try using XStreamAliasType, but it didn't work)...

Comment: Whether serializing or deserializing is irrelevant for the naming relationship to work or not. You would probably learn a lot by serializing an looking into the resulting XML, though. Did you try `xstream.alias("KEYWORD", String.class);`?

Comment: I did... 
I understand what you're saying, and yes I did try to serialize the Bean into the XML, which produces a list of <string> for the "<keyword>" element. 

Check this out: 
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/xstream-user/JAgMtKfE54w

I'm having a conversation w/ Jorg about that

Answer (score 0):

I changed your code in two respects:

- I added a '/' to the closing tag  of `<KEYWORDS>`
- I added a call to xstream.alias() for mapping "KEYWORD" to the String class

That outputs "keyword_1" for me:

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    String xml = 
        "<CATALOG>\n"+
        "  <PRODUCTS>\n"+
        "    <PRODUCT>\n"+
        "      <PRODUCTID>123</PRODUCTID>\n"+
        "      <PRODUCTNAME>TEST NAME</PRODUCTNAME>\n"+
        "      <DESCRIPTION>TEST DESCRIPTION</DESCRIPTION>\n"+
        "      <KEYWORDS>\n"+
        "        <KEYWORD>keyword_1</KEYWORD>\n"+
        "        <KEYWORD>keyword_2</KEYWORD>\n"+
        "        <KEYWORD>keyword_3</KEYWORD>\n"+
        "        <KEYWORD>keyword_n</KEYWORD>\n"+
        "      </KEYWORDS>\n"+  // <--
        "    </PRODUCT>\n"+
        "  </PRODUCTS>\n"+
        "</CATALOG>";
    XStream xstream = new XStream();

    xstream.alias("KEYWORD", String.class);  // <--
    xstream.processAnnotations(Catalog.class);
    xstream.processAnnotations(Product.class);

    Catalog catalog = (Catalog) xstream.fromXML(xml);
    System.out.println(catalog.products.get(0).keywords.get(0));
}
```